# Get formatted output from eclipse template variable

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I make an eclipse java template that allows generating java code that eases the repeating part of registering code for a java method. Example:

Assume that the class description is like so:

```
class A{
    public static void methodName(String s, int i, Object o) {
    }
}
```

Now, what I want is to make a template that does something somewhat like this:

```
"${enclosing_type}.${enclosing_method}(" + ${variable1} + ", " + ${variable2} + ", " + ${variable3} + ")"
```

Given the available Eclipse variables I know, the idea would probably be:

```
"${enclosing_type}.${enclosing_method}(" + ${enclosing_method_arguments(" + \", \" + ")} + ")"
```

Where that argument would signal the glue to the join of each element of the enclosing_method_arguments. The result of the format would be:

```
"A.methodName(" + s + ", " + i + ", " + o + ")"
```

If there's an even better alternative, I'm open for suggestions.
This is meant to be used with a piece of code that is executed a **LOT**,

Unfortunately, String.format() (and related) "solution" is not an option here due to the requirement above and due to other inherited requirements with what I'm working on. It must generate that code in that format no matter what, unfortunately.

I'm open to any plugins that allow that and, if eclipse doesn't have it, I'm open to make a plugin myself... In case of me having to do a plugin please do show me the resources required to make it.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to write a custom variable resolver. It is defined by [org.eclipse.ui.editors.templates extension point](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/index.html?cp=2_1_1)

You could implement a custom `resolver` that points to Java context (its id is `java` defined in [jdt.ui](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/plugin.xml)).

I don't know any plugins that would provide what you need out of the box.

If you are new to Eclipse plug-ins you might need to read the [documentation on extending Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/nav/2). However, the task is really simple, so you should be able to do it after just a glimpse over the docs.

Comment: I see... I'll try that way and see how it goes. I'll report back later with the result (and maybe votes)

Comment: I need more information. That link to the manual is not teaching me anything useful (to my disappointment, for an official manual) and I can't seem to be able to find an extension point to attach my code to related to template variables...

Comment: I have updated the link to `templates` extension point. It was wrong before and surely added to your confusion. Sorry for that. I will try to expand the response to guide you more.